# A lot of one-value read or one many-value read in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I would like to use firebase to load a 2D map in my site. There will be dynamic load of fields when user scroll map and also show changed map-fields.

But i am interested what is more efficient.

Read list of values even if i need only about 50% of loaded fields (e.g. 100 loaded fields)

```
geoRef.startAt(null, start).endAt(null, end).on('value', callback);


maybe better: 
geoRef.startAt(null, start).endAt(null, end).once('value', callback);
geoRef.startAt(null, start).endAt(null, end).on('child_changed', callback);
```

or read a lot of single value (e.g. 50x)

```
geoRef.child(valueX).child(valueY).on('value', callback);
```

These reads will be triggerd for every user scroll. So that there will be a lot of 50x vs 1x(50%) reads.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to answer this question specifically without details. Are we talking 1000 records that are each 10 bytes or 1 million records that are each 5MB?

Data size and network bandwidth are the consideration here, not the number of connections. Firebase holds a socket opened to the server, so the overhead of establishing TCP connections is not a concern (as it would be with multiple HTTP requests), although the time it takes a request to return from the server (latency) is.

This leaves only two considerations: how much data and how many records.

For instance, if my system contains 1002 records and I want 1000 of them, and each is 1KB in size, it's going to be faster to simply request them all at once (since this requires only the latency of waiting for one response from the server). But if I want 10 of them, requesting them separately would likely be faster.

Even more ideal would be to segment them using priorities or split them cleverly into multiple paths by category, time frame, or another context. Then I can retrieve only segments of the data as a single transaction.

For example:

```
/messages/today
/messages/yesterday
/messages/all_messages
```

Now, assuming `today` is measured in hundreds and the payload is 1KB, I can just grab this whole list and iterate it client side any time I'd like--not worth the energy to grab them individually. If this is my common use case, perfect.

And assuming `all_messages` is measured in the millions of records, each about 1KB, then to grab 100 messages from here, I'll naturally gravitate to snagging each one individually.

Comment: I'm not sure this the right place to ask, but is it a common and recommended technique to do advanced data filtering on the client side instead of the server side? From what I understood, any advanced filtering on the server side isn't even possible.

As an example, a website similar to craiglist: requesting buy/sell offers within specific price range, in certain location, and in certain product category. We'd have to fetch all the indexes and them make out the wanted list of buy/sell IDs to be fetched on the client side? Isn't that very inefficient?